# How do i dual boot kde neon and ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, kde, dual-boot

Hi I would like to know how hard it is to dual boot kde neon and ubuntu. I have kde neon on one hard drive and I would like to use another hard drive for ubuntu. (Ubuntu and kde neon will be on different hard drives)
and for those who need more info I'll be getting the new ubuntu 19.10 
So can you tell me if this is possible and how
I hope this won't be hard. BTW
And I have a t430s laptop with kde on it and I'm replacing my broken optical drive for a 2nd hdd caddy that will fit in there.

Comment: In my experience easy.  My desktop contains Ubuntu 18.04 LTS & Ubuntu 19.10 in a dual-boot setup.  I did nothing except partition the system as I want it (I only have a single drive; your dual drive should be easier), and install; the second installed version took ownership of the MBR (master boot record; or first 512 bytes of my HDD) (you can post-install change this easily).  You should still backup, and I always use 'something-else' & partition myself. but it's your choice.  *I have another machine with 3 hdds & 7 OS (debian & ubuntu) systems installed*

Answer (score 0):

You seem quite well prepared -- only one big thing missing: the BIOS mode in which you want to start your system.

Your model seems a bit aged, and I could not find uefi mentioned. This is no problem. That would mean you just stay on "legacy" (or MBR, your only) BIOS boot mode.

I have listed some **boot scenarios** in a similar situation:
[grub2-unable-to-detect-a-fresh-...-intstallation](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/546579/grub2-is-unable-to-detect-a-fresh-fedora-intstallation/546674#546674)

Have a look. The problem is often that the user does not know about the whole thing and the installing program tries to guess, and grub also has to be told where to put which kind of boot loader.

If you are lucky, then ubuntu's installing programm will guide you and everything should work. Get some specific info from **ubuntu's wiki** etc. after you read this. But before you install ;)

In your two-drive-dual-boot I see two methods for selecting at startup:

1. go to **BIOS** for each change of boot order (just like you are able to select the CD-ROM drive for booting).
2. boot as now into first **grub**. grub can then find the second kernel and initrd and load them with the second `root=` argument. OR *chain load* the second grub - like you have to on MBR and (old?) lilo.

Grub or Uefi BIOS are the **glue** between the computer's legacy firmware and the kernel at startup (system boot): Has to be at the right spot, nut just "there".

Check out grub or uefi in wikipedia to get another view of these interesting but tricky problems when you boot an OS.

**Any OS**. BIOS and also grub are exactly made for running any OS, and for choosing which one at startup. Linux, BSD, etc, Windows: any OS running on amd64/intel aka x86.

And always make sure you know how to use your **rescue system** from an external storage device (USB "pen") in case you break something - adding a second internal drive (SSD or HDD) to boot from with MBR is quite some step.